# Ionic intercept incoming sms

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, sms, mobile-development

I am working with the latest version of Ionic. I need to intercept sms received from a specific number. I use [cordova-sms-plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms) as on the documentation of Ionic but this one comprises only the sending of SMS. I tested several other plugins but to no avail. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution to my problem. I just followed this tutorial => https://enappd.com/blog/automatically-read-sms-in-ionic-4-apps/42/